# What ABI does Rust use for passing structs

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64, llvm-ir, abi

On x86_64 system, when the return value is less than or equal to 16 bytes, it is passed through the register RAX and RDX, and when the return value is greater than 16 bytes, it is passed through the first sret parameter. However, it seems that rust does not follow this rule.

In C profram example:

```
struct test_struct {
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

struct test_struct foo() {
    struct test_struct a = {1,2,3};
    return a;
}
```

This function in llvm ir is as follows:

```
define dso_local { i64, i32 } @foo()
```

We can see that the return value is passed through the register.

In Rust profram example:

```
pub struct test_struct {
   a: i32,
   b: i32,
   c: i32,
}
pub fn foo() -> test_struct {
   let data = test_struct {
       a: 0,
       b: 1,
       c: 2,
   };

   data
}
```

This function in llvm ir is as follows:

```
define void @_ZN7example3foo17hd5941535b576c335E(ptr sret(%test_struct) %0) unnamed_addr
```

We can see that the return value can be passed through the first sret parameter.
So what ABI does Rust use for passing structs

Answer (score 2):

The Rust ABI is unspecified and should not be relied upon.

If you want to use the C ABI, specify the function as `extern "C" fn ...`. Make sure that all structs involved are also `#[repr(C)]`.

Comment: `#[repr(C)]` is not strictly required, there are a few exceptions like `Box`, so instead of ensuring all structs are that, you have to ensure all structs are C ABI save, which is a little more lenient.